# self.title only works in viewDidLoad?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

When I use self.title in any other place except viewDidLoad, nothing happens.  I am trying to change the text of the navigation bar on my UIView.

I am trying to get the text off of a table cell when selected, and then make the title of the UITableView (which will show right after I touch the table cell) the text of the table cell.  What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UINavigationItem`'s title inherits the value from the associated `UIViewController`'s `title`, but it does this by copying the value at the time that it needs it. Once your navigation item has been added to a `UINavigationBar`, in order to change what it displays you need to modify the item itself, e.g. by assigning to `self.navigationItem.title`.